# Highcharts Pie Donut: Error when clicking URL

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to make the links to work in my chart but I receive the following error when clicking one of the Pie Donut Versions:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

I uploaded it to my web server and I see that it simply returns as "undefined". (www.mywebsite.com/undefined)

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(function () {

var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = ['Agua', 'Gas', 'Electricidad'],
    data = [{
        y: 17.5,
        color: '#c27ba0',
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Agua',
            categories: ['Lavadora', 'Fregadero de platos', 'Inodoro', 'Regadera del baño'],
            data: [5, 5, 5, 5],
            url: ['https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com'],
            color: '#c27ba0'
        }
    }, {
        y: 17.5,
        color: '#f1c232',
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Gas',
            categories: ['Sistema Calefacción', 'Calentador de agua', 'Estufa', 'Secadora de ropa'],
            data: [5, 5, 5, 5],
            url: ['https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com'],
            color: '#f1c232'
        }
    }, {
        y: 72,
        color: '#e06666',
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Electricidad',
            categories: ['Aire acondicionado', 'Ventilador', 'Plancha', 'Secadora de Cabello', 'Focos',
                'Lavadora', 'Televisión', 'Refrigerador', 'Horno de microondas', 'Aspiradora', 'Licuadora',                                                 'Estereo', 'Cafetera', 'Computadora','Tostador','Extractor'],
            data: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
            url: ['https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com'],
            color: '#e06666'
        }
    }],
    browserData = [],
    versionsData = [],
    i,
    j,
    dataLen = data.length,
    drillDataLen,
    brightness;


// Build the data arrays
for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
        name: categories[i],
        y: data[i].y,
        color: data[i].color,
        url: data[i].url
    });

    // add version data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
        brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
        versionsData.push({
            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
            color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
        });
    }
}

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ahorra Energia'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fuente de Energia
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            center: ['50%', '50%'],
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Energia',
        show: false,
        data: browserData,
        size: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
            },
            color: '#ffffff',
            distance: -60
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Versions',
        data: versionsData,
        size: '80%',
        innerSize: '50%',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    location.href = this.series.options.url;
                }
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.point.name
                },
                color: 'black',
                distance:-10
        }
    }]
});
```

});

My code is in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tirux/aevrsoew/) too.

I also tried to make it work by moving the Point->Events->Click function from the series to plotOptions with no avail.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I only found one URL (point to yahoo.com) in your code.  Should all three of the inner pie slices have URLs?  Also, are you only expecting the user to click on the inner pie slices or can they also click on the outer pie slices?  How should those clicks be handled?

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that your jsfiddle doesn't match the code you posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you were seeing is JSFiddle telling you that there's something wrong with a URL you're requesting.  This was caused by your code not finding the correct URL.  To fix it, change the click function to this:

```
click: function(event) {
    location.href = event.point.url;
}
```

Also, when your code is adding items to the `versionsData` array, you need to add a URL object to each item.  Change your `versionsData` code to this:

```
  versionsData.push({
      name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
      y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
      color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get(),
      url: data[i].drilldown.url[j]
  });
```

In the end, your code should look like this:

```
$(function() {

  var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = ['Agua', 'Gas', 'Electricidad'],
    data = [{
      y: 17.5,
      color: '#c27ba0',
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Agua',
        categories: ['Lavadora', 'Fregadero de platos', 'Inodoro', 'Regadera del baño'],
        data: [5, 5, 5, 5],
        url: ['https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com'],
        color: '#c27ba0'
      }
    }, {
      y: 17.5,
      color: '#f1c232',
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Gas',
        categories: ['Sistema Calefacción', 'Calentador de agua', 'Estufa', 'Secadora de ropa'],
        data: [5, 5, 5, 5],
        url: ['https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com'],
        color: '#f1c232'
      }
    }, {
      y: 72,
      color: '#e06666',
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Electricidad',
        categories: ['Aire acondicionado', 'Ventilador', 'Plancha', 'Secadora de Cabello', 'Focos',
          'Lavadora', 'Televisión', 'Refrigerador', 'Horno de microondas', 'Aspiradora', 'Licuadora', 'Estereo', 'Cafetera', 'Computadora', 'Tostador', 'Extractor'
        ],
        data: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        url: ['https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://yahoo.com'],
        color: '#e06666'
      }
    }],
    browserData = [],
    versionsData = [],
    i,
    j,
    dataLen = data.length,
    drillDataLen,
    brightness;


  // Build the data arrays
  for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
      name: categories[i],
      y: data[i].y,
      color: data[i].color,
      url: data[i].url
    });

    // add version data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
      brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
      versionsData.push({
        name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get(),
        url: data[i].drilldown.url[j]
      });
    }
  }

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Ahorra Energia'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Fuente de Energia'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        shadow: false,
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Energia',
      show: false,
      data: browserData,
      size: '60%',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
        },
        color: '#ffffff',
        distance: -60
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Versions',
      data: versionsData,
      size: '80%',
      innerSize: '50%',
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function(event) {
            location.href = event.point.url;
          }
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.point.name
        },
        color: 'black',
        distance: -10
      }
    }]
  });
});
```